# how to cast object to get Id in C#

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I'm using nhibernate and have an issue when some of objects are null. ie

Region is null and i get a null ref when i go userProfile.Region.Id

Of course throughout my app i could do something like

```
var regionId = (Model.UserProfile.Region != null) ? Model.UserProfile.Region.Id : 0);
```

But i think ideally i would like null objects ids to equal 0.

Is this achievable? Is this desirable?

### Phase 2 ## using an interface

i now have:

```
   interface IEntity
    {
        int GetIdOrZero();
    }
```

and

```
public class Region :IEntity
    {

        public virtual int Id { get; set; }    

        public int GetIdOrZero()
        {
            return (this != null) this.Id : 0;
        }
    }
```

what is the best way to test if region is null?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't change the behaviour of a null reference, but you could define an extension method that does what you want:

```
public static class RegionExtensions
{
    public static int GetIdOrZero(this Region region)
    {
        return region == null ? 0 : region.Id;
    }
}
```

**Edit:**

```
public interface IEntity
{
    int Id { get; }
}

public class Region : IEntity { ... }

public static class EntityExtensions
{
    public static int GetIdOrZero(this IEntity entity)
    {
        return entity == null ? 0 : entity.Id;
    }
}
```

Comment: hmm, i do like this method. Tho i have 40 entities. Is there a way to do something more robust. ie so that i don't have to create 40 extension method.

Comment: You have 40 different classes, each with an `Id` property? You could introduce an `IEntity` or `IHasId` interface (with an `Id` property) and have the entity classes implement that.

Comment: cool, think thats a great solution! See above is that what you had in mind. If not sure how to test if the object is null inside of "Region"

Comment: "`this != null`" - you still need the extension method. `this` can never be null; instead, the caller gets a `NullReferenceException` when they call your method.

Comment: great, thanks for taking me thru this. Very cool, i can see lots of handy uses for this in my app.